# How to use the output of matlab function in another function ?

Tags: matlab, function

I'm working on Iris recognition system for my degree project (put in mind i have no background in Matlab and i had no courses or anything in it , but i had to use it to implement my project ><) .

I'd like to ask , how can i use the output of a Matlab function in another function ?
Like how to take the output of a function , let's say "Segmentation" function , and pass it or use it in another function , like "Normalization" for example .

Is there any way to store it in a variable or something like that like in other programming languages ? 
I hope you guys got what i mean & I hope i'll get an answer :)

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi. This is a very basic question implying that you really need to get yourself familiar with the MATLAB language. There are great tutorials on [www.mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html).

Comment: Thank you Eitan for this fast reply :) , i know i really need to be familiar with Matlab & i really wish that i can get some courses ! I'm not gonna go in this & tell the long boring story but i have to work on it this semester that means no much time to learn Matlab , i just need to learn at least the basics . Can you suggest me what tag in mathworks should i read ?

Comment: Look up mathworks new programming learning system called Cody. You start by programming really basic challenges. I think it looks like a great way to learn. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody

Answer (score 0):

Just add an output argument to your first function, and an input argument to your second function, like so:

```
function theOutput = doSomething()
    theOutput = someValue;
```

Then, the second function:

```
function doSomethingElse(theInput)
    disp(theInput); % Will print value of someValue returned from first function, assuming you call doSomethingElse passing this value
```

If you are unfamiliar with these basic concepts, however, I would recommend reading up on the MATLAB language in general. Remember that the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/) contains a wealth of information on most topics. For this specific problem, see the [function keyword](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/function.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much , i really appreciate your help :). I'll try it & see if i can do it .

Answer (score 0):

take 3 minutes to read any matlab getting started guide,

this one for example

http://alice.nc.huji.ac.il/~hvuag/neuromath/math/Matlab_Tutorial.pdf

Matlab is HUGE, and it can take you years to explore every corner, 
the upside is , that you can be productive from minute 2. the easy things are very much straight forward.

to answer your question, variable assginment is trivial

```
a=max(1,2)
b=max(a,3)
```